# Solving for one variable in terms of another

Tags: linear-algebra

Express Q in terms of P

$$(P)\sqrt{ (P^2 - Q)/ Q} = 
(1 - P)/2 $$

Here's what I did -
Step 1: I squared both sides -
$$(P^2)(P^2 - Q)/Q = (1-P)^2 / 4 $$

Then ...
$$(P^4 - P^2Q)/Q = (1-P)^2 / 4$$

Then ...
$$4P^4 - 4P^2Q = Q(1-P)^2$$

Then I got stuck .. Pls help thanks !!

Comment: I made a slight adjustment to your formulas based on how you were working with them. Your work indicates you intend $Q$ to be in the denominator of the entire expression under the radical, I hope that's true. Specifically, I added parentheses to indicate that *both terms* are to be divided by $Q$, so I think you meant $\frac{P^2-Q}{Q}$ rather than $P^2-\frac QQ$, right? Likewise with the other side.

Comment: Rewrite $(P^2-Q)/Q$ as $P^2/Q-1$ and there is a single occurrence of $Q$ left.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** So far, your work is correct.

The goal is to isolate $Q$ on one side of the equation. The form of the equation now is $$a+ bQ=cQ$$ (here $a,b,c$ are expressions involving only $P$). So bring the two terms containing $Q$ to the same side, then factor $Q$ out of that side to get $$a=(c-b)Q$$ You should see what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

After the part you've done:
$$4P^4 - 4P^2Q = Q(1-P)^2$$
$$\implies 4p^4=Q(1-2P+5P^2)$$
$$\implies Q=\frac{4p^4}{1-2P+5P^2}$$